# Array to string conversion issue

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to check in a table row if a columnname exists and if its equal to an object in an array. If this exists it should be added to $update_fields.

But $data[$col] gives me the error: "Array to string conversion".

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Erro!: " . mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
         foreach ($row as $col => $val) {

            if(!empty($data[$col])) {
                      $update_fields[] = $col .'='. $data[$col];                                
            }
         }
  }
```

Comment: `if (isset($data[$col])) { //do something }`

Comment: What is `$data`? You don't define it anywhere in your code.